# i want to send a variable to xxx.php how i do it?

Tags: php

i want to send a variable to xxx.php how i do it???

Comment: i already have the variable in $_POST['text'] and i want to pass it to xxx.php

Answer (score 6):

GET request would be

```
xxx.php?variable=something
```

and accessing `$_GET['variable']` in php side would work.

Answer (score 5):

- Pass it as a [command line argument](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)
- Set it in another PHP file and then [include it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
- Put it in the query string then access it from `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`
- Put it in the POST data then access it from `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`
- Put it in a cookie then access it from `$_COOKIES`
- Put it in a session variable then access it from `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1):

You can send the variable by using the GET method as:

```
http://www.example.com/welcome.php?fname=Peter
```

and access it from script as: `$_GET["fname"]`

Answer (score 1):

Via the URL
for example
`www.yoursite.com/xxx.php**?**myVar1=myValue1&myVar2=myValue2`
seperate vars by **&**

or you can do it using a form , via **Get** 
`<form method='get'>`

Step2: 
 in your PHP document
$_GET['myVar1']
$_GET['myVar2']

Answer (score 0):

```
xxx.php?variablename=variablevalue
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send the variable using $_POST or using $_SESSION to pass value of variable from one file to another

Answer (score 0):

use query string in your code.

For example

$a = "myval" ;

< a href="xxx.php?var=$a" >

Get values by usnig $_GET['var'] , This would give you the query string value.

Comment: i alredy have the variable in $_POST['text'] and i want to pass it to xxx.php

Comment: store the $_POST['text']  to $a ; 
pass the $a as query string values.

Answer (score 0):

It's best you read up the basic about POST and GET first.

Here's a simple tutorial to get you started: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Answer (score 0):

Via query string or in the header of the page

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as query string:

```
xxx.php?your_var=var_value
```